# Swift can't connect actions from storyboard with viewcontroller extension file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I'm trying to connect a button touchUp action with an extended view controller class file but can only see the main viewcontroller file and interfaces. Any suggestions?